# SOQL FIELDS function gives error even with limit

Tags: apex, soql

I'm trying a simple query for contacts to return all fields since this will be a general class for looking up contacts to be used in multiple areas.  I tried using the new FIELDS function but keep getting an error stating

```
The SOQL FIELDS function is not supported with an unbounded set of fields in this API
```

This is the query in question and it is not an unbounded query.

```
Contact con =
                    [SELECT FIELDS(ALL),
                            (SELECT Id, AccountId, ContactId, IsActive, StartDate, EndDate, Role__c
                            FROM AccountContactRelations)
                    FROM Contact
                    WHERE Id = :recordId
                    LIMIT 1];
```

Has anyone else encountered this error or gotten the FIELDS(ALL) function to work?

Comment: See the Bounded and Unbounded Queries section in the [official FIELDS() docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fields.htm), which spells out why it can't be used in Apex classes

Answer (score 13):

`FIELDS(ALL)` works in the Developer Console ("Query" tab) and other APIs (REST, SOAP, etc), just not Apex. You can use `FIELDS(STANDARD)`, but not either of the other two options while writing Apex. This is an Apex-only restriction to prevent blowing up heap limits.

Comment: I tried using FIELDS(CUSTOM) or FIELDS(STANDARD) and both still caused the same error.

Comment: @byarsawich If using this in a class, make sure you're using a later API version (I think 52?) or you'll get a compile error. I know this works in my org, I've used it already.

Comment: Currently only FIELDS(STANDARD) is supported in Apex. See Brian Miller's comment to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

FIELDS(ALL) is not currently supported on Unbounded queries.
You can try with FIELDS(STANDARD).

Also it's recommended to only query the fields you need to improve performance.

Docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fields.htm